# How to make the fastest possible bottom-up tree transformer in JavaScript? Should I manage memory on my own?

Tags: javascript, performance, algorithm, tree, asm.js

I am implementing a bottom-up tree transformer in JavaScript. It will be used for an interpreter for a supercombinator reducer, so this algorithm has to be as fast as possible, as it affects every program built on top of it. This is my current implementation:

```
function transform(tree,fn){
    var root = tree,
        node = tree,
        child,
        parent,
        is_node,
        dir;
    root.dir = 0;
    while(true) {
        is_node = typeof(node)==="object";
        dir = is_node ? node.dir : 2;
        if (dir < 2)
            child = node[dir],
            node.dir++,
            child.parent = parent = node,
            child.dir = 0,
            node = child;
        else if ((changed = fn(node))!==undefined)
            changed.parent = parent,
            changed.dir = 0,
            node = changed;
        else
            if (!parent)
                return node;
            else
                parent[parent.dir-1] = node,
                node = parent,
                parent = node.parent;
    };
};

// TEST
var tree = [[1,2],[[3,4],[5,6]]];
console.log(
    JSON.stringify(transform(tree,function(a){
        if (a[0]===1) return [3,[5,5]];
        if (a[0]===5) return 77;
    })) === "[[3,77],[[3,4],77]]");
```

This is obviously far from optimal. How do I make the transformer the fastest possible? Maybe instead of looking for a faster algorithm, I could manage the memory by myself, and use `asm.js`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of options, going from easiest-but-slowest to fastest-but-trickiest.

## Using regular JavaScript

This is pretty much what you are doing at this point. Looking at your algorithm, I don't see anything that can really be suggested that would show anything more than an insignificant increase in speed.

## Using asm.js

Using asm.js might be an option for you. This would offer a speed increase. You don't go in to a lot of details of where this system will be used, but if it works, it shouldn't be terribly difficult to implement something like this. You would likely see performance increases, but depending on how you are planning to use this, it might not be as substantial as you would like (for something like this, you'd probably see somewhere between 50%-500% increase in speed, depending how efficient the code is).

## Build it in a different, compiled, typed language.

If speed is really at a premium, depending on your use case, it might be best to write this program (or at least this function) in a different language which is compiled. You could then run this compiled script on the server and communicate with it via web services.

If the number of times you need to transform the tree in a short amount of times is huge, it won't be much of a boost because of the time it would take to send and receive the data. However, if you are just doing relatively few but long-running tree transformation, you could see a huge benefit in performance. A compiled, typed language (C++, Java, etc) will always have better performance than an interpreted, typeless language like JavaScript.

The other benefit of running it on a server is you can generally throw a lot more horsepower at it, since you could write it to be multi-threaded and even run on a cluster of machines instead of just one (for a high-end build). With JavaScript, you are limited to generally one thread and also by the end-users computer.

Comment: Interesting! The idea is to port a whole framework to run in the browser, so I'm really for the asm.js suggestion. The problem is that I have no idea on how I should do it. My approach would be to implement my own memory management system and garbage collection, and the chances I mess up with that are huge. So how you'd go? Remember the system is nothing but a big binary tree, so maybe that could be of use for organizing the memory better?

Comment: I don't know if you would really get a large benefit from doing your own memory management and GC. The big benefit of asm.js is that it approaches typed and compiled language. The more ou add on top, the more likely it will hurt performance. If you have short-running transforms, neither would help. If longer running, a bit of clean-up might help. You could also make it -appear- faster but making it async. If you are sticking with JavaScript, you should attempt a basic asm.js version and then post that code in a new question to get actual feedback on that code.

Comment: OK, just a question. TBH I'm not really sure how to write asm.js properly. Maybe it is a better idea to write the code in C and compile to asm.js?

Comment: Honestly, if I was going to write this, I would probably write it in something else as well. asm.js isn't final by any means, and documentation for it is a bit tricky to find. Using something like C would probably save you some hair pulling down the line. =)

Comment: You mean C->Asm or just C? As in, using a server to do the work? The problem here is that the code is used in a place where performance is **essential**: it is called whenever someone edits a node in a structural tree editor, so waiting for the server to answer before refreshing the screen would worsen the experience considerably. :(

Comment: Using C->Asm might be sufficient. The trick is to identify which is more likely to happen: many, quick changes or fewer, larger changes. If the performance is already decent, but you want it better, using asm.js is probably good enough. However, if it is pretty far because you are doing fewer, larger changes, letting a server process it than return it will probably end up being better. On a good server, your only adding about 100ms of overhead, so if it is that much faster processing, then its a benefit. If you need super speed, clustering servers to make it process crazy fast is even better.